# Direct sum of two vector subspaces, show that $V = V_1 \oplus V_2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $$V_1 = \{(x,2x,3x)~|~x \in \mathbb{R}\}$$ $$V_2 = \{(0,y,z)~|~y,z \in \mathbb{R}\}$$ of the row vector 3-space $\mathbb{R}^3$.

How do i show that $V_1 + V_2 = \mathbb{R}^3$?

For a start $V_1+V_2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ because both $V_1,V_2$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}$.

Now we try to prove $\mathbb{R}^3 \subseteq V_1+V_2$. Let $a \in \mathbb{R}^3$, that is for each $a \in \mathbb{R}^3$, there exists $v_1 \in V_1,v_2 \in V_2$ such that $a = v_1+v_2$. But i do not know how to continue.

Comment: You can use the dimension formula $\dim(V_1+V_2)=\dim(V_1) + \dim (V_2) - \dim(V_1\cap V_2)$. The point is that in this case RHS is quite easy to compute.

Comment: @user160738, in my opinion, what you do is the best approach. You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $P=(a, b, c) \in \mathbb{R}^3$; we have: 
$$(a, b, c)=(a, 2a, 3a)+(0, b-2a, c-3a);$$ 
notice that $(a, 2a, 3a) \in V_1$ and $(0, b-2a, c-3a) \in V_2$.

---

---

Also if we have $(a, b, c)=P_1+P_2$; for some $P_1=(x_1, 2x_1, 3x_1) \in V_1$ and $P_2=(0, x_2, x_3) \in V_2$.
Then we must have: 
$$ 
             \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             a=x_1+0 , \\
             b=2x_1+x_2 , \\
             c=3x_1+x_3 , \\ 
             \end{array}
             \right.
$$ 
so we can conclude that $x_1=a, x_2=b-2a, x_3=c-3a$;
i.e. $P_1=(a, 2a, 3a), P_2=(0, b-2a, c-3a)$;
which implies the uniqueness of $P_1, P_2$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Find the values of $b_1, b_2, b_3$ such that  $$a=(a_1,a_2,a_3) = (a_1,2a_1,3a_1)+ (b_1,b_2,b_3)$$

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is that $$V_1 = \operatorname{span}\{(1,2,3)\},\ V_2 = \operatorname{span}\{(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$$ which implies that $$V_1+V_2 = \operatorname{span}\{(1,2,3),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}.$$

Since $$\det\begin{pmatrix}
1& 2& 3\\
0& 1& 0\\
0& 0& 1
\end{pmatrix} = 1,$$
these three vectors are linearly independent and thus $\dim(V_1+V_2) = 3.$ Finally $V_1+V_2\subseteq \mathbb R^3$ gives $V_1+V_2 = \mathbb R^3$ because dimensions are equal.

Comment: Seems a very neat answer and currently still learning bout basis and dimensions! So i will this method the easiest in time to come.

Comment: @ilovewt, I just wanted to show that there are different kinds of methods you can use. In my opinion the most important thing you can get out of this, if you are at the beginning of your studies in linear algebra, is the first line, that is that you can recognize $\{(x,2x,3x)\mid x\in\mathbb R\} = \{x(1,2,3)\mid x\in\mathbb R\} = \operatorname{span}\{(1,2,3)\}$, and similarly for the other. This alone lets you show easily that any $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb R^3$ is of the form $\alpha(1,2,3)+\beta (0,1,0) + \gamma (0,0,1)\in V_1+V_2$.

Comment: Hi, yes regarding your comment i do see that they are of span $\{(1,2,3)\}$ and the other span$\{(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$, but could you elaborate a bit on why you said that this alone lets your easily show that any $(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ is of that form you mentioned?

Comment: @ilovewt, I might have been too rash with that. It is - if you are comfortable enough with bases. It might be a personal preference, but if I wrote $(x,2x,3x)+(0,y,z) = (a,b,c)$, from that I wouldn't be sure that solution always exists. I would have to go one step further and write linear system $(x,2x+y,3x+z) = (a,b,c)$ and then I would have to go about solving the system. But I guess it's just kind of thing you get used to over time, I'm not actually interested in solving the system, just knowing if there is solution or not is enough. (cont'd)

Comment: To that goal, although equivalent, some ways to write the same thing are more transparent than others.